Create Custom Keyboard View using Custom Entry Handler in .NET MAUI
I've read the many posts on StackOverflow and other places on making custom keyboards, but have not found an approach that will work for my .NET MAUI cross-platform project.
For example, I built this keyboard in Xamarin Forms(Android)
https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-create-a-custom-keyboard-with-xamarin-forms-android-4fa3b83dad1d
As Xamarin Forms is going to be deprecated I have to migrate Custom Render to Custom Handler/Mapper but the Entry Renderer used in Xamarin Forms(Android) to display Custom Keyboard view is not supported in .NET MAUI.
I would appreciate any help.
Thank you.
I've tried to add Custom Handler in Android using below link:
https://github.com/jsuarezruiz/xamarin-forms-to-net-maui/blob/main/Handlers/.NET%20MAUI/CustomHandlers/CustomHandlers/Platforms/Android/CustomEntryHandler.cs
but for showing my Custom Keyboard view on Entry there is no workaround

Handlers do not randomly draw stuff on your screen.

You need a custom control with bindable property. Also, note that the needed Xamarin nugget packages probably can't be applied to the Maui project.
